# Function to see if word is isogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

> An isogram is a word that has no repeating letters, consecutive or
> non-consecutive. Implement a function that determines whether a string
> that contains only letters is an isogram. Assume the empty string is
> an isogram. Ignore letter case.

I have the following as the furthest I can make it. But the goal is trying to say that 'moOse' is not an isogram. It says to not worry about casing. I am not sure how to differentiate between 'o' and 'O'.

```
    char_list = []
    for char in string:
        if char.isalpha():
            if char.islower():
                if char in char_list:
                    return False
                else:
                    char_list.append(char)
    return True
```

My script returns true because it sees the 'o' and 'O' differently. How do I get it to not differentiate? I tried adding `.islower()`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just uppercase the string before checking whether it contains duplicate letters:

```py
def is_isogram(string):
    char_list = []
    for char in string.upper():
        if char in char_list:
            return False
        char_list.append(char)
    return True
```

You can make this faster by using a set rather than a list:

```py
def is_isogram(string):
    char_list = set()
    for char in string.upper():
        if char in char_list:
            return False
        char_list.add(char)
    return True
```

And you can make this even more concise by using the `len()` function:

```py
def is_isogram(string):
    return len(string) == len(set(string.upper()))
```

Comment: Thanks, why does the set() help with this?

EDIT: NVM I see it after looking it up. I appreciate it. 

I do not quite understand why the len() helps though?

Comment: `len()` gives the length of the string / number of elements in the set. If all of the letters are unique, then the size of the set will be the same as the number of letters in the string. If there are repeated letters, the size of the set will be smaller, since sets don't contain duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

Short and straightforward solution:

```
def check_isogram(text):
 return len(set(text.lower())) == len(text)
```

Comment: Instead of "try this", describe why this is a good solution for the problem.

Comment: This works I'm not quite sure why this works though. I appreciate the help